# Spyder Startup command creates SparkSession object and *two* Web UIs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spyder

In my Spyder preferences, I have the following IPython console Startup command:

```
  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession ; spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
```

This launches *two* Web UIs on ports 4040 and 4041.

When I comment out the Startup and issue the same command from the IPython prompt in Spyder, I only get *one* Web UI on port 4040.

When the Startup command is not commented out, I find that the following
steps are needed to kill the two resulting Web UIs:

- Issuing spark.stop() kills the 2nd one only
- Issuing sys.exit() (doesn't restart kernel) leaves first one still running
- Issuing exit() restarts the kernel and kills the first one

***Why does the Startup command create *two* Web UIs?***  I only have one Spyder console,
and hence, presumably one kernel.

I installed Python, Spyder, Java, and PySpark using Anaconda on Windows 10.

Depending on how unique my problem is, it could be difficult for others to comment on the reason and remedy.  However, the *apparent* cause doesn't seem all that unorthodox, at least to my newbie eyes, i.e., the Startup command above.  Therefore, ***it would be helpful of others could corroborate the problem*** in their Spyder/Spark setup, or the absence thereof.  That is, two Web UIs when the Startup command is set, but only one Web UI if the same command is issued at the Spyder console instead.  Thanks.

### Annex: Why restart IPython console so often?

I get heartbeat timeout warnings that I [posted about
before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76848115). A side-effect of these timeouts, however, is that many
invocations to objects in other namespaces yield the error
`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`:

```
# works
spark.read? # The "?" suffix pulls up the doc string in Spyder

# Don't work
spark.read.csv?
df.show() # df is a DataFrame object
df = spark.read.csv(
   r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes.csv",
   header=True )
spark.stop()
```

After restarting the kernel using `exit()` and recreating all
objects, the above commands work again.

Answer (score 0):

From trial and error, I find that the restarted kernel from issuing
`exit()` starts a new Web UI *in addition* to the old one.  Issuing
`spark.stop()` only kills the old one, as seen by entering its URL
`localhost:404x` (could be 4040, 4041, 4041, etc.).  It's easy to keep
track of which is old vs. new by noting the up-time on the Web UI.

In Spyder's preferences, if the "IPython console" `Startup` field does
*not* contain the following, then `exit()` will cause the remaining
Web UI to stop responding as well:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession ; spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
```

If the above `Startup` command *is* set, however, then `exit()` starts
a new Web UI *and* the old one also continues to respond, as seen by
visiting its URL `localhost:404x` and noting the up-time.  I do not
know why the old Web UI continues to run.

I do have the above `Startup` command set because it's too
inconvenient to issue every time I restart the IPython console with
`exit()`.
Consequently, I end up with old and new Web UIs.  I just have to
remember to issue `spark.stop()` to kill the old Web UI after issuing
`exit()` and after the IPhython console reconnect to a kernel.

**Afternote 2023-10-15:** The above procedure seems to avoid an extra
(presumably)  obsolete Web UI and I seem to be able to get Spark
functionality afterward, but it generates the following error and
stack trace for the following code for reading a CSV file, adapted
from
[here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/#read-directory)
[1]:

```
# Both syntaxes for specifying option header as True are accepted
df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv") \
      .option("header","true") \
      .schema(schema) \
      .load(r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes1.csv")

df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv") \
      .option("header", True) \
      .schema(schema) \
      .load(r"C:\cygwin64\home\User.Name\tmp\zipcodes1.csv")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[12], line 1
    df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv") \
<...snip...>
  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326 in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.read.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LiveListenerBus is stopped.
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addToQueue(LiveListenerBus.scala:98)
<...snip...>
   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

***Empirically, therefore, what seems to work*** is to issue
`spark.stop()` prior to `exit()` (which sometimes yields a deluge of
error messages) and *not* issue `spark.stop()` after the IPython
console reconnecst to the kernel.  It will leave an extra (presumably)
obsolete Web UI.

**Notes**

**[1]** The
[page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/#read-directory)
provides code to define the `StructType` object `schema`, but the
following imports are missing:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
```