# In Spyder's console, what is "exit" without brackets?

Tags: python, pyspark, spyder

Recently, I found that `exit()` restarts the interpreter
kernel while `sys.exit()`, which [makes a difference in
PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193055).

Typing `exit` also exits.  How can I determine whether it
corresponds to `exit()`, `sys.exist()`, or something else?

In Spyder, I can call up the doc string of a method or object
by suffixing the name with `?`, e.g., `>>> exit?<return>`.
It *seems* to be for `exit()`, as the method takes an argument.
How can I be sure?

Also, how can I be sure that it is the right doc string for
`>>> exit<return>`?